# feathers socketIO filters are not working on CLI based service?

Tags: feathersjs

I try to follow docs to apply filters limiting socket-io results send to the client.
Services have been generated by cli and so i first modified the function there.
After no success, i inserted the filter function directly into the service:

```
service.filter(function(data,connection){
    debugger;
    return data;
})
```

but debugger doesn't hit and also if i apply conditions with returning false, they are not applied.

Do i miss something?
hanks and Greets

Comment: I think it would help if you will add the version of youe feathers cli.

Comment: When are you expecting the filter to run?

Comment: I worked on it a bit more and i think, i had a misunderstanding of the filters function. My intention was using them to FILTER document mostly for the find command. I realized its about sending CUD information to the respective clients. I have not integrated filtering in the before HOOKS. I guess thats OK.
Thanks for your reply :)